# Disable/Enable Mouse and Keyboard Input into Microsoft RDP

Tags: remote-desktop, rdp

I am trying to run on a remote machine an RPA robot that uses UI image recognition.  How do I disable/enable my computer's mouse and keyboard input on the fly in Microsoft RDP client?

This method should be similar to how one transfers the mouse/keyboard controls from the host PC to the guest machine in VirtualBox or VMWare.